# How to create two navigation properties to one model (EF6 Code First)

Tags: c#, .net, code-first, entity-framework-6

Using EF6 Code First convention, I want to create model with two foreign keys to the same table. For instance, now I have **Team** model:

```
public class Team
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Match> Matches { get; set; }
}
```

and **Match** model:

```
public class Match
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Int32 TeamHomeScore { get; set; }
    public Int32 TeamAwayScore { get; set; }

    public Guid TeamHomeId { get; set; } // I want these properties to be foreign keys
    public Guid TeamAwayId { get; set; } //

    public virtual Team TeamHome { get; set; }
    public virtual Team TeamAway { get; set; }
}
```

But after project running I've got next exception:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Matches_dbo.Teams_TeamHomeId' on table 'Matches' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint.

Any recommendations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server is returning an error because it can't handle multiple cascade paths. The multiple path is the **Match** having many **Team** properties.

Set cascade on delete to false.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
                    .HasRequired<Team>(i => i.TeamHome)
                    .WithMany(i => i.Matches)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Since there is no cascade delete, you must delete the team's matches first before deleting the team itself.

Answer (score 2):

try this, if you use migrations. Migrations are not smart everytime, you should interreput the code sometimes.

```
public class Match
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Int32 TeamHomeScore { get; set; }
    public Int32 TeamAwayScore { get; set; }

    public Guid TeamHomeId { get; set; } // I want these properties to be foreign keys
    public Guid TeamAwayId { get; set; } //

    [ForeginKey("TeamHomeId")]
    public virtual Team TeamHome { get; set; }
    [ForeginKey("TeamAwayId")]
    public virtual Team TeamAway { get; set; }
}
```

and then you will add below to your DataContex.cs

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
               .HasRequired(a => a.TeamHome )
               .WithMany()
               .HasForeignKey(u => u.TeamHomeId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
               .HasRequired(a => a.TeamAway )
               .WithMany()
               .HasForeignKey(u => u.TeamAwayId);
}
```